# VDS SSH free -m - что показывает эта команда?

Tags: vds, ssh, vps, linux

Вот что мне показывает команда free -m

```
free -m             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cachedMem:           387        353         34          0         12        254-/+ buffers/cache:         85        301Swap:            0          0          0
```

Это получается что памяти всего 387 мб?

и может такое быть что показывает столько а памяти реально больше мне выделили в vds?

Answer (score 1):

Да у вас 387 мегабайт. Нет, реально не больше.